# Find input[matInput] within mat-form-field with ViewChild/ContentChild inside custom directive

Tags: angular, angular-material

There are many `mat-form-field` elements in our application. Some of them contain `MatSelect` dropdowns, but most of them contain `input[type=text]` elements with `matInput` attribute.

I have a directive `ClearButtonDirective` with very general `selector: 'mat-form-field'` - that's intentional, so that it modifies all `mat-form-field`s. The directive inserts a "clear button" into all `mat-form-field` elements, which clears the value of the input element when clicked, and it only appears when there's some value in the text field.

I have **two issues**, both of which are related to the fact that I don't know how to find the input element with `@ViewChild` or `@ContentChild` decorators (to be honest I'm not yet sure what's the difference between these two).

1. In `onClearClick()` the value is cleared (using `MatFormFieldControl` child), but **I also want to focus the input field** after that - how? I need the reference to it...
2. I only want **the directive to act (insert clear buttons) on those `mat-form-field`s which contain `input[matInput]`, but not others**, such as those that contain `mat-select` - how? Again, for this I need to be able to detect/find the `input[matInput]` child.

I don't want to modify existing templates to achieve this, so I can't add any element references or CSS classes.

**[Working example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-so-example?file=src/app/clear-button.directive.ts)** - the first three boxes are `mat-form-field`s with `matInput`, the 4th one contains `mat-select`.

Thank you! ❤

`clear-button.directive.ts`:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef,  ContentChild,  Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter,  Output,  Renderer2, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MatFormFieldControl } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { distinctUntilChanged, map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Component({
  selector: 'button.clear-button',
  template: 'Clear',
  host: {
    '[hidden]': 'hidden',
    '(click)': 'onClick()',
  }
})
export class ClearButtonComponent {
  @Output() clearButtonClick = new EventEmitter<void>();
  hidden = true;

  onClick() {
    this.clearButtonClick.next();
  }
}


@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-form-field'
})
export class ClearButtonDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  private buttonComponent: ComponentRef<ClearButtonComponent>;

  @ContentChild(MatFormFieldControl) control: MatFormFieldControl<any>;

  constructor(
    private _viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private _resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private _hostElement: ElementRef,
    private _renderer: Renderer2,
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const buttonFactory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ClearButtonComponent);
    this.buttonComponent = this._viewContainer.createComponent(buttonFactory);
    this._renderer.appendChild(this._hostElement.nativeElement, this.buttonComponent.location.nativeElement);

    // Listen to button clicks:
    this.buttonComponent.instance.clearButtonClick.subscribe(this.onClearClick.bind(this));

    this.control.stateChanges.pipe(
      startWith(true),
      map(_ => !!this.control.value),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
    ).subscribe(shouldHideButton => this.buttonComponent.instance.hidden = !shouldHideButton);
  }

  onClearClick() {
    this.control.value = '';
  }

}
```

`app.component.html`:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

  <!-- clear button should appear here - works fine -->
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>First name - matInput</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
  </mat-form-field>

  <!-- clear button should appear here - works fine -->
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>First name - matInput</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="lastName" />
  </mat-form-field>

  <!-- clear button should appear here - works fine -->
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Type anything - matInput</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="text" formControlName="someField" />
  </mat-form-field>

  <!-- clear button should ***NOT*** appear here - how to achieve that? -->
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>MatSelect - clear button <b>NOT</b> wanted here</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="someSelect">
      <mat-option value="one">First option</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="two">Second option</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

`app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl('John'),
      lastName: new FormControl('Doe'),
      someField: new FormControl(),
      someSelect: new FormControl('one'),
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the combination of both approaches above seems to be valid, though.

But if you want to make it more performant please combine them together.

Please make sure you will always follow the documentation of each decorator you will use in the future. As written in [T. Sunil Rao's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66246110/1126349), it is better to rely on a callback for a [ContentChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild) in [ngAfterContentInit](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentInit).

I would put a specific function before the whole logic and also follow [Guard Clauses pattern](https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html)

```
if (this.isNotEligible()) {
  return;
}

// rest of the code here

/**
* Determine if you need to continue with logic
*/
isNotEligible(): boolean {
    return this.control.controlType !== "mat-input";
}
```

There is no need to do such an expensive operation like `instanceof`.

If you want to make fewer problems for your application avoid storing obsolete pointers.

```
const buttonComponent = this._viewContainer.createComponent(buttonFactory);
```

There is no need to store it as a reference inside the directive context, it is already mapped in the Hierarchy model once you've created it by `ViewContainerRef`. If you want to read more [Here is nice documentation](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection)

You could also use less jumping from pointer to pointer

```
const clearButtonInstance = buttonComponent.instance;
```

And the most important thing is the usage of the `bind`. For your subscriber function, you should provide an anonymous function or lambda function.

```
// Listen to button clicks:
clearButtonInstance.clearButtonClick.subscribe(() => {
  this.control.ngControl.control.setValue(EMPTY_VALUE);
  (this.control as MatInput).focus();
});
```

As you can see I've used typecasting as proposed by [Chellappan வ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66246215/1126349). Honestly, I don't think if this is the right approach, but as a start, it will work for you. You can eventually change it to a more appropriate function or just use additional `ChildContent` with `MatInput`, but either way, in more complex components (e.g. multiple elements) you would have trouble determining what element you wanna focus to on and also check of eligibility will be more complicated so be aware.

As a bonus, please make sure you will use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` whenever you can. You will avoid issues in production for `Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`

Here is my updated version of your [Snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-so-example-4dupqy)

Answer (score 2):

Nice Questions!

> In onClearClick() the value is cleared (using MatFormFieldControl child), but I also want to focus the input field after that - how? I need the reference to it...

You have already referenced the control, just need to focus using native HTML Element

```
onClearClick() {
  this.control.value = "";
  ((this.control as unknown) as HTMLElement).focus();
}
```

> I only want the directive to act (insert clear buttons) on those mat-form-fields which contain input[matInput], but not others, such as those that contain mat-select - how? Again, for this I need to be able to detect/find the input[matInput] child.

The control has a property controlType which can check its type

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (this.control.controlType === "mat-input") {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, please implement ngAfterContentInit instead of ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-so-example-zhg4gn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fclear-button.directive.ts

Answer (score 2):

**Issue 1:**

All input[text] element will implement [DefaultValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/DefaultValueAccessor#selectors) by default. So you can check something like this to add btn dynamically.

```
 if (this.control.ngControl.valueAccessor instanceof DefaultValueAccessor) {
      const buttonFactory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(
        ClearButtonComponent
      );
      this.buttonComponent = this._viewContainer.createComponent(buttonFactory);
      this._renderer.appendChild(
        this._hostElement.nativeElement,
        this.buttonComponent.location.nativeElement
      );
 }
```

**Issue 2:**

[matInput](https://github.com/ChellappanRajan/components/blob/master/src/material/input/input.ts#L90) directive provides MatInput instance to MatFormFieldControl class, Hence we can call [focus](https://material.angular.io/components/input/api#MatInput) method on it to focus input.

```
 onClearClick() {
    //Use setValue method on control to set empty value on control.Otherwise it will not propagate to parent formGroup.
    this.control.ngControl.control.setValue('');
    (this.control as MatInput).focus();
  }
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/find-inputmatinput-within-mat-form-field-with-viewchild-content?file=src/app/clear-button.directive.ts)